# I want to break a string stored in an array at the '\n' character?

Tags: c, string, fgets

My file contains three lines, after using fgets to read the file into an array, I want to break the three lines at the new line character and print the three lines separately out on the console and if possible store the three lines in three different arrays.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int main()
 {
    FILE *infile;
    char data[BUFSIZ],*pa,token_seperator[]={"\n"};

   infile=fopen("example","r");

   while((fgets(data,BUFSIZ,infile)!=NULL))

   pa=strtok(data,token_seperator);

   while(pa!=NULL) 
   {
    printf("%s\n",pa);
    pa=strtok(NULL,token_seperator);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Execute `fgets` 3 times.

Comment: `char *app; app=strchr(data,'\n'); if (app!=NULL) *app=0;` On windows you have to trunc using '\r' instead of '\n'. (Or you may test both '\n' and '\r').

Comment: I see that the first while reads all the file till the end ... then you are parsing only the last line of the file!

Comment: fgets man page says "Reading stops after an EOF or a newline".As BLUEPIXY said execute fgets three times and print/store it each time

Answer (score 1):

There is no any sense "to break the three lines at the new line character" because a line can contain no more than one new line character.

If you need to read each line in a separate array then just declare a two-dimensional character array. If you want you can remove the new line character appended to each line by the call of `fgets`.

So the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3

int main( void )
{
    FILE *infile;
    char data[N][BUFSIZ];

    infile = fopen( "example", "r" );

    if ( infile )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        for (; n < N && fgets(data[n], BUFSIZ, infile); n++)
        {
            data[n][strcspn(data[n], "\n")] = '\0';
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", data[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering, what if the case is that I do not know how many lines I have to read from a file and I would like to count the number of characters in each line using strlen?

Comment: How come the condition for if loop is infile? Does infile ever return positive integer or 0 for the loop to be executed as true or false respectively?

Comment: @AMD If the number of lines is undefined then you need dynamically reallocate a two-dimensional array of strings.  As for the condition in the for loop then if the pointer is unequal to NULL it is considered as true.

Answer (score 0):

You will need allocate some memory to do this, just because you don't know how many line you finally will have nor the size of each one.

I suggest you the next code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef SplittedString char[BUFSIZ]

int main()
{
   FILE *infile;
   char token_seperator[]={"\n"};
   SplittedString data;
   SplittedString myLines[50];   // you can modify this number to hold more lines
   int i=0;
   infile=fopen("example","r");

   while((fgets(data,BUFSIZ,infile)!=NULL) && i < 50){ //prevent array overflow
       printf("%s\n",data);
       strcpy(myLines[i], data);
       ++i;
   }
 }
```

Comment: `fgets` stops after EOF or newline.

Comment: That's not the only change needed. `*pa` and `token_separator` types are wrong. I'd suggest you to compile before posting.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs my bad, i didn't pay enough attention on what i was writting, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I was wondering if you forgot to declare an array named data?

Comment: Sorry guys, doing things fast never end well XD

Answer (score 0):

The function below,`truncCrLf`, deletes from ASCII-0 strings the first occurence of the CR and/or LF codes. This is what you are looking for because the `fgets` function reads from the file till these ASCII codes (0xA and/or 0xD).

This function acts under both Linux and Windows SO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * truncCrLf(char *data)
{
    char *app=NULL;

    app = strchr(data, '\n');
    if (app)
      *app=0;

    app = strchr(data, '\r');
    if (app)
      *app=0;

    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  char test[200];

  strcpy(test,"Hello world\n");

  printf("%s......\n",test);

  truncCrLf(test);

  printf("%s......\n",test);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A much cleaner way is to replace `truncCrLf(test);` with `test [ strcspn(test, "\r\n") ] = 0;`

Comment: I didn't know this... Thanks! :)

Comment: @WeatherVane. I tried what you say, but it doesn't run! I tried also to use strcspn(test, "\n") because I'm under Linux, but it didn't run.